# p2p application in Silverlight 5

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-oob

With the upcoming 5th version of Silverlight, can we implement a p2p Silverlight OOB application? If so, would it work on both Windows and Mac? Life would be a lot easier with WPF, but I like the fact that SL is not limited to Windows.

P.S. If no OOB is an option, that's even greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. No p2p support in SL5 I afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create such an application, but the target host needs to serve a 'socket policy file' on a special port, which makes it difficult in practise (firewalls, etc.)